# Set CSS based on child element

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have the following nav:

```
<div id="nav">
<div id="subnav">
<li><a href="#">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
</div>
</div>
```

The following jQuery:

```
$('#subNav:not(:has(a))').css('background','none');
```

So `#subNav's` background is `'none'` when its empty.

I also want to set `$nav` background to `'none'` at this point, some kind of and??? How can I do this within this same function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)** selector.

```
$('#subNav:not(:has(a))').css('background','none').parent().css('background','none');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#subNav:not(:has(a))', '#nav').css('background','none');
```

You mean that?

Comment: He wants to set the `#nav` background to none only when the first selector matches. I guess your selector will do it every time irrespective of match. Correct me if I am wrong.